# Can syntax errors be caught in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

[MDN states](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/SyntaxError):

> A SyntaxError is thrown when the JavaScript engine encounters tokens or token order that does not conform to the syntax of the language when parsing code.

But if there's a syntax error, how could the program even run in the first place?

How can JavaScript syntax errors even be caught?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12219154/ignore-javascript-errors-in-a-page-and-continue-executing-the-script

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's runtime errors that can be caught with try-catch, not syntax errors (**if you `eval` your code**  you can handle syntax errors in the evaled code but that's just weird).

I'd recommend you read these:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Statements#try...catch_Statement
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Statements#Exception_Handling_Statements

Comment: +1 on the evaling code into excistance and catching exceptions on the syntax errors being possible, but wonky.

Comment: native javascript's JSON.parse throws SyntaxErrors

Answer (score 34):

You cannot use `try-catch` blocks to handle syntax errors as they are thrown while the code is being parsed and not while it's running.

However you can use `window.onerror` and figure out that there's an error. You must ensure that the `onerror` function is defined in a separate script tag and not in the tag in which the error may be present!

Eg:

This will not work, because the script is yet to start running when the error is thrown:

```
<script>
  window.onerror = function (e) {
    console.log('Error: ', e);
  };
  console.log('a'');
</script>
```

This will work:

```
<script>
  window.onerror = function (e) {
    console.log('Error: ', e);
  };
</script>
<script>
  console.log('a'');
</script>
```

[jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/svn4yha7/1/)

Answer (score 17):

In the JS world, SyntaxError CAN be a runtime exception. This can arise, for instance, when trying to parse a JSON response that isn't JSON format. The server can send back lots of types of responses, so if you send a HTML body response to your request that's expecting JSON in the body, you're going to get a `SyntaxError` thrown in the JS. In such a case, you would get an error message that looks something like this: `SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unrecognized token '<'`.

But there are other runtime SyntaxErrors you could get as well. Mozilla has a list of some here: [SyntaxErrors for JSON parsing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/JSON_bad_parse)

You may want to catch these in your code. You can do so with a generic try/catch block like this:

```
try {
  JSON.parse('<html></html>');
} catch (e) {
  console.log("I catch & handle all errors the same way.");
}
```

OR you can look for the SyntaxError specifically:

```
try {
  JSON.parse('<html></html>');
} catch (e) {
  if (e instanceof SyntaxError) {
    console.log("I caught a pesky SyntaxError! I'll handle it specifically here.");
  } else {
    console.log("I caught an error, but it wasn't a SyntaxError. I handle all non-SyntaxErrors here.");
  }
}
```

Mozilla has even more [info on JS errors and handling them](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error).

Comment: Yup. I think this is really a confusing name. This `SyntaxError` is not really a syntax error in the language sense (e.g.: you started a string with quotation mark but don't have the closing quotation mark anywhere, etc). The latter indeed cannot be caught. `SyntaxError` is really just a runtime error. It just has an unfortunately confusing name.

Comment: Checking if it is instanceOf SyntaxError. It helped me.

Answer (score 4):

You can catch ***programmer-generated and runtime exceptions*** but you cannot catch ***JavaScript syntax errors,*** though you may handle them in some browsers using ***window.onerror***.

This is taken from the book `JavaScript- The Complete Reference by Thomas-Powell` which I like very much. You can refer to the code examples in that book.

Comment: Do you have a code example? Which browsers do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

You specifically cannot catch parser-generated SyntaxErrors since they are thrown by the parser, which has no idea what try/catch blocks do. More info on that - [Learning how programming languages work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515940/learning-how-programming-languages-wor)

There is a way to catch SyntaxErrors that are generated during code execution. This method is slow, and I would not recommend it. You can catch SyntaxErrors using `eval()`.

```js
var code = `function() {
doSomething()
somethingElse()
var x = 5 + 5
// No ending curly brace` // The code to be run using eval

try {
  eval(code) // Try evaluating the code
} catch (e) {
  if (e.name !== 'SyntaxError') throw e // Throw the error if it is not a SyntaxError
  
  console.log('A SyntaxError has been caught\n\nDetails:\n' + e) // It is a SyntaxError
}
```

Alternatively, you could use `new Function()`, which is up to 93% faster - https://jsben.ch/1HLQ1

```js
var code = `function() {
doSomething()
somethingElse()
var x = 5 + 5
// No ending curly brace` // The code to be run using eval

try {
  new Function([], code) // Try evaluating the code
} catch (e) {
  if (e.name !== 'SyntaxError') throw e // Throw the error if it is not a SyntaxError
  
  console.log('A SyntaxError has been caught\n\nDetails:\n' + e) // It is a SyntaxError
}
```