# How to catch a SyntaxError in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, exception, syntax-error

I am trying to catch a Syntax error in my code, but it does not get into catch block

```
( function(){
try {

 throw fn(){};  // I am trying to generate some syntax error here

}catch (exception){
    console.log(exception.message);
  }

})();
```

Edited

If you notice here the wrong syntax is inside the try block, so as a javascript theory it has to first go inside catch block, then whats use of a built-in object SyntaxError

```
( function(){
try {

throw fn(){};
}catch (exception){
   if(exception instanceof SyntaxError)
   console.log("Syntax Exception occured" + exception.message); 
}
})();
```

but this is not handled in program instead I am able to see "Uncaught SyntaxError" directly in console

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateOn (<anonymous>:895:140)
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap (<anonymous>:828:34)
    at Object.InjectedScript.evaluate (<anonymous>:694:21)
```

Comment: Use `jslint` http://www.jslint.com/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Syntax errors can be caught in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963045/syntax-errors-can-be-caught-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot catch syntax error simply because the whole script is not evaluated (due to the syntax error...
Only thing I can imagine is to get the code as string, then pass it to `eval()` and wrap the eval into a `try catch`...

But earth will collapse if you do that...

```js
var test="var x= 1.5.5;"; //this is a syntax error
var test2="var x=1;"
try {
  eval(test)
  alert(test + ' is a valid script')
} catch(e) {
  alert(test + ' is not a valid script')
}
try {
  eval(test2)
  alert(test2 + ' is a valid script')
} catch(e) {
  alert(test2 + ' is not a valid script')
}
```