# javascript try catch statement not working in my code

Tags: javascript, error-handling, try-catch, uncaughtexceptionhandler

1. I got "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token" error.
2. And try to catch with 'try ~ catch' but it's not working.

   ```
   function a(){
     try{
      var img1 = "=="";  <#-- it occurs error -->
     }catch (e) {
       console.log("image error:" + e.message);
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: Is that your exact code? Also you can't catch syntax errors (outside of eval at least).

Comment: I occurs error Intentionally to test catch statement. But it can't catch the error.

Comment: AFAIK syntax error is not exception

Comment: Syntax errors are checked at the parsing time, `try .. catch` is executed at the running time, which will never take place because a syntax error has interrupted the script.

Comment: As others mentioned, syntaxError will not be catch, instead try this http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/error.shtml

Comment: Then how to handle it? Actually, variable 'img1' is decryption string, but sometimes server send wrong string.

Comment: At first (if on your control) I'd tried to fix an occasionally occurring incorrect information at the server-side, or if that is not possible, you could rather ask how to fix the real problem at hands, not for a hack to fix it.

Comment: You should correct the error cause by syntax error. Sounds like you generate this javascript by code, right? you should know how to make the javascript syntax correct.

Comment: possibly a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963045/can-syntax-errors-be-caught-in-javascript)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can syntax errors be caught in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963045/can-syntax-errors-be-caught-in-javascript)

Comment: jumi lee, **please read**: [What should you do when someone answers your question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 5):

You have a syntax error and you can not catch a syntax error.

This error is checked at the parsing or validation time of your code. The `try .. catch` statement is executed at the running time. And because of this it was not functioning.

If you eval or parse (for ex. JSON) your code you can handle syntax errors **only**. Or you can create a syntax error like this:

```
try {
  throw new SyntaxError('Hello', 'someFile.js', 18);
} catch (e) {

  console.log(e.message);  // "Hello"
  console.log(e.name);  // "SyntaxError"
}
```

*For the `eval` handled or by self created syntax errors:*

> A SyntaxError is thrown when the JavaScript engine encounters tokens or token order that does not conform to the syntax of the language when parsing code.
>
> *From **[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/SyntaxError)***

Try this:

```
    function a(){
      try{
       var img1 = "==\"";
       //but you have to put some error here without parsing or validation error of your code.
      }catch (e) {
        console.log("image error:" + e.message);
      }
    }
```

I would like to recommend you read:

- **[`try...catch` Statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Statements#try...catch_Statement)**
- **[Exception Handling State](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Statements#Exception_Handling_Statements)**
- **[Syntax Error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/SyntaxError)**