# How can I make the error handler catch error?

Tags: node.js, express, error-handling

```
require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const { logger } = require("./middleware/logger");
const { errorHandler } = require("./middleware/errorHandler");
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3400;

//middleware
app.use(logger);

//errorHandler

app.use((error, req, res, next) => {
  console.log("err");
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on ${PORT}`);
});
```

express catches the error before it reaches the error handler. I want to route all the error to the error handler.

I tried to create syntax error but express default error handler catches that also.

Comment: Show the code which throws the error.

Comment: ```app.use(loggr);
        ^

ReferenceError: loggr is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\project\Backend\StudentAttendence\server.js:9:9)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1226:14)    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1280:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1089:32)    
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:930:12)    
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
:23:47```

Comment: just changed the name of the logger to create reference error

Comment: Take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963045/can-syntax-errors-be-caught-in-javascript